# Mod_rewrite only by subdomain root redirect to php file

Tags: mod-rewrite, subdomain

I got a phpbb3 CMS running and customized a lot about it.
Now i'm trying to achieve that if somebody use the link `http://xxx.domain.tld`
it will redirect internal to `http://domain.tld/forum.php?subdomain=xxx`

The Problem i've got there exactly is that if you see now the content of `http://domain.tld/forum.php?subdomain=xxx` inside of it a css link to a other php file which lies in the same Folder as the called forum.php.

The best way were if only the subdomain root called it will internal redirect to the forum.php and any other request will handled normal.

with my many trys my best solution was this

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([a-zA-Z]+)\.domain\.tld$ [NC]  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !^(.*\.(jpg|png|gif|css|js))$  
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ forum.php?subdomain=%1 [L]
```

but as you can guess the problem is with the dynamic css file, so I hope you can help me ^^

and besides: sorry for my bad english x|

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't you just add an exception for the php script that generates the css?

Like so:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([a-zA-Z]+)\.domain\.tld$ [NC]  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !^(.*\.(jpg|png|gif|css|js))$  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !path_to_css_script\.php$  
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ forum.php?subdomain=%1 [L]
```

Comment: About a way like that i also Thought, but as i Said the CSS script lies in the Same Folder as the called forum.php so that way it won't Work. Also i have a chat.php in the Root folder that will called with Ajax :/

Comment: Why would it make a difference if it's in the same folder?

Comment: the REQUEST_URI would only contain as i suggest "style.php" so there is no real Path in it and i already tried to make the Condition `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^style.php$`

Comment: Omg now i've found the right soloution. I've tried to make the Condition `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(style|chat).php$` but the caret was wrong thougth x| so i guess i need to thank you^^